# Understanding Bomb Lab Phase 5 (two integer input)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering, binary-bomb

I am currently stuck on bomb lab phase 5. My phase 5 is different from most other phase 5's I've found online, as it is the input of two integers. Here is the assembly code:

```
   0x0000555555555536 <+0>:     sub    $0x18,%rsp
   0x000055555555553a <+4>:     mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x0000555555555543 <+13>:    mov    %rax,0x8(%rsp)
   0x0000555555555548 <+18>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x000055555555554a <+20>:    lea    0x4(%rsp),%rcx
   0x000055555555554f <+25>:    mov    %rsp,%rdx
   0x0000555555555552 <+28>:    lea    0x1914(%rip),%rsi        # 0x555555556e6d
   0x0000555555555559 <+35>:    callq  0x555555554f60 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
   0x000055555555555e <+40>:    cmp    $0x1,%eax
   0x0000555555555561 <+43>:    jle    0x5555555555bd <phase_5+135>
   0x0000555555555563 <+45>:    mov    (%rsp),%eax
   0x0000555555555566 <+48>:    and    $0xf,%eax
   0x0000555555555569 <+51>:    mov    %eax,(%rsp)
   0x000055555555556c <+54>:    cmp    $0xf,%eax
   0x000055555555556f <+57>:    je     0x5555555555a3 <phase_5+109>
   0x0000555555555571 <+59>:    mov    $0x0,%ecx
   0x0000555555555576 <+64>:    mov    $0x0,%edx
   0x000055555555557b <+69>:    lea    0x165e(%rip),%rsi        # 0x555555556be0 <array.3418>
   0x0000555555555582 <+76>:    add    $0x1,%edx
   0x0000555555555585 <+79>:    cltq   
   0x0000555555555587 <+81>:    mov    (%rsi,%rax,4),%eax
   0x000055555555558a <+84>:    add    %eax,%ecx
   0x000055555555558c <+86>:    cmp    $0xf,%eax
   0x000055555555558f <+89>:    jne    0x555555555582 <phase_5+76>
   0x0000555555555591 <+91>:    movl   $0xf,(%rsp)
   0x0000555555555598 <+98>:    cmp    $0xf,%edx
   0x000055555555559b <+101>:   jne    0x5555555555a3 <phase_5+109>
   0x000055555555559d <+103>:   cmp    %ecx,0x4(%rsp)
   0x00005555555555a1 <+107>:   je     0x5555555555a8 <phase_5+114>
   0x00005555555555a3 <+109>:   callq  0x555555555b25 <explode_bomb>
   0x00005555555555a8 <+114>:   mov    0x8(%rsp),%rax
   0x00005555555555ad <+119>:   xor    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x00005555555555b6 <+128>:   jne    0x5555555555c4 <phase_5+142>
   0x00005555555555b8 <+130>:   add    $0x18,%rsp
   0x00005555555555bc <+134>:   retq   
   0x00005555555555bd <+135>:   callq  0x555555555b25 <explode_bomb>
   0x00005555555555c2 <+140>:   jmp    0x555555555563 <phase_5+45>
   0x00005555555555c4 <+142>:   callq  0x555555554ec0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
```

The list of numbers I've inputed is this:

[image]

So far from my understanding, two conditions need to be met:

1. edx must equal 0xf, meaning the first input has to be 5, 21, 37, etc. (Add 16 each time)
2. ecx is compared to rsp, which is 15, so we need ecx to equal to 15

What I know so far:

1. first input cannot be 15, 31, 47, etc.
2. Changing the second input does not affect the ecx
3. first input is directly correlated to edx

Questions:

1. Where is the second input used?
2. Is it true that the first input has to be 5, 21, 37, etc?

Comment: As to your questions: 1) on line `+103` 2) no

Comment: @Jester so I looked at your reply to another question which is extremely similar to my question, actually the same exact question. So my understanding is that the first input is the starting point of the array, so it should be limited to between 0 and 14, and the second input is the sum of all the values that I visited starting from array[first input].

Comment: If this is a duplicate of another question, please link it so future readers can find it if their search turns up this question first.

Comment: @cinos hi,  I had same problem, I couldn't understand, I must have ecx 15 too, but I couldn't figure it out. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

compare %ecx is 115 line 103
your answer turns out to be 21 115

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is : 5 115. I have given a detailed explanation for phase_5 here: https://techiekarthik.hashnode.dev/cmu-bomblab-walkthrough?t=1676391915473#heading-phase-5

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).